# Using HTTP requests for inter process communication

Tags: tcp, httpserver, interprocess

As a learning experience, I would like to create a small cluster of inter communicating processes, on a single machine, sending and receiving requests from each other without a shared parent.

I have some understanding of the TCP/IP stack, but I have no idea what is used to implement this practically. From a 10'000 ft view, what are the steps needed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a proxy. Does not matter whether it is a real proxy server or a self-oriented one (using python socket library for instance) then you can fire simple curl(within GET or POST method) and parsing it using your proxy.
I guess if you look for request library you may have some conclusions. 
PS: I am pythonist, but you may found some equivalent for other languages as well. 
Cheers